# When adding a Drupal data field, the seconds data is readonly as checked as a data to collect?

Tags: drupal, date, drupal-7

I am trying to add a new date field to my content type, what is weird is that the seconds checkbox is readonly and marked as checked? I only want the user to select the date fields ( Day, Month, Year)

[image: Seconds fields is readonly and it is checked]

Any ideas how to solve this?